# Using easelJS to free transform shapes on pressmove

Tags: javascript, canvas, transform, easeljs

I want to replicate the basic functionality of a free transform tool (no rotation), by dragging on the border of a easeljs Shape and adjusting the container to match it. I'm currently using the scaleX and scaleY properties and it sort of works but is not quite right.

If you do one scaling transformation it works pretty well. However if you release, then do another scaling transformation, it jumps very glitchily, and can occasionally break sending the x/y coordinates all the way to stage 0. Any help on this issue would be great!
http://jsfiddle.net/frozensoviet/dsczvrpw/13/

```
//circle
var circle = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics()
    .beginFill("#b2ffb2")
    .drawCircle(0, 0, 50));
circle.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

//create the border as a seperate object
var cBorder = new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().setStrokeStyle(10)
    .beginStroke("#000").drawCircle(0, 0, 50));
cBorder.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

//add both to the container
circleContainer.addChild(circle);
circleContainer.addChild(cBorder);

var cWidth = circleContainer.getBounds().width;
var cHeight = circleContainer.getBounds().height;

//find initial mouse position relative to circle center
cBorder.on("mousedown", function (evt) {
    //initial mouse pos
    this.initial = {
        x: Math.abs(-(circleContainer.x - evt.stageX)),
        y: Math.abs(circleContainer.y - evt.stageY)
    };
});

//set the relevant circle axis scale to ratio of mouse pos/initial mouse pos
cBorder.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
    //current moouse pos
    this.offset = {
        x: Math.abs(-(circleContainer.x - evt.stageX)),
        y: Math.abs(circleContainer.y - evt.stageY)
    };

    if (this.initial.x > this.initial.y) { 
        //sides
        circleContainer.scaleX = this.offset.x / this.initial.x;
    } else if (this.initial.x < this.initial.y) {
        //top/bottom
        circleContainer.scaleY = this.offset.y / this.initial.y;
    } else {
        //diagonals
       circleContainer.scaleX = this.offset.x / this.initial.x;
       circleContainer.scaleY = this.offset.y / this.initial.y;
    }
    stage.update();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `initial` calculations don't account for the change in the scale of the circle. You would have to transform the coordinates using `localToGlobal`. Fortunately, there is an even easier way:

```
this.initial = {
    x: Math.abs(evt.localX),
    y: Math.abs(evt.localY)
};
```

You can also turn on `ignoreScale` on the border, which makes it not stretch:

```
createjs.Graphics().setStrokeStyle(10,null,null,null,true) // The 5th argument
```

Lastly, your bounds setting might work for your demo, but it is not correct. Your circle draws from the center, so it should be:

```
cBorder.setBounds(-25, -25, 50, 50);
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tfy1sjnj/3/

Comment: Thank you, this solved that issue. One last question, I forked your fiddle and modified it by adding a function that zooms in the canvas on mousescroll, how would I account for that scale change of the whole canvas - but not the scale of the circle - in the pressmove listener? http://jsfiddle.net/frozensoviet/y923tjbh/

Comment: I tried something like `evt.stageX / totalZoom` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Nevermind, with a bit of work I figured it out. Thank you for all the help though!

Comment: Do you have an updated fiddle? I had a quick look at it, but wasn't able to get it working. I was going to recommend you avoid stage transformations (use a container instead).